# Java multi-threading and socket questions

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

So, im trying to understand this example that teaches about multithreading:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

The client starts with:

```
 public class KnockKnockClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println(
            "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

while the server instead starts with:

```
if (args.length != 1) {
    System.err.println("Usage: java KKMultiServer <port number>");
    System.exit(1);
}

    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    boolean listening = true;

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)) { 
        while (listening)
```

What are those arguments? If i enter "localhost 4444" on the run properties of the project it still doesn't run.

How does the server/client both select the same port?

Will multi-threading still be possible if I write `int portNumber = "4444";` instead? The server shouldnt be able to listen to the port "4444" after the first client connected right?

Comment: Please note that only the client accepts both host and port parameters; the server only accepts the port.

Definitely the server can continue to listen on a port after it has accepted a connection. But two servers can't be listening on the same port.

Comment: @9000 whats the point of the arguments? why does this example have the host name and socket the way it is?

Comment: Something like [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets) might clarify things for you,